# Which different variables does range clause return for different data structure types like map?

Tags: loops, dictionary, go

When looping through an array, the first variable returned is the index, and the second variable returned is the value:

```
array := []int{2, 3, 4}
for index, value := range array {
    fmt.Printf("Index: %s, Value: %s\n", index, value)
}
```

What is returned when looping through map with the range clause. It is not the same as for array. There cannot be an index of a map anyway. Can we get key names?

Comment: A `map` in Go is a hash/dictionary structure like in many other languages. Why would there be an index for something that doesn't have a deterministic result and isn't stored as a list?  If you're thinking about a map reduce style iteration, then that takes a list as input. But, it has no relation to the map structure.  https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

Comment: `Where is the index of the loop returned in this case?` What index? Why would you expect there to be an index when iterating over something that has no index?

Comment: Or, viewed another way, where the index in a slice or array is an integer, the "index" in a map is the key - so when you get the key, you *are* getting the index, as far as a map is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation of range clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements), following are the returned values for different kinds of types that it is used with:

- array or slice a `[n]E`, `*[n]E`, or `[]E`:

  - **1st value:** index `i int`
  - **2nd value (optional):** `a[i]` E (element at index i)
- string s string type

  - **1st value:** index `i int`
  - **2nd value (optional):** rune `int` (the unicode of the character. to get the actual character, simply cast like this: `string(value)`)
- map m `map[K]V`:

  - **1st value:** key `k K`
  - **2nd value (optional):** value `m[k]` V
- channel c chan E:

  - **1st value:** element `e E`

[Simplified read here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

Comment: The official documentation for the [For statements with range clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) is in [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).